# Flash player installation issue

Tags: windows-xp, flash, windows-installation, windows-installer, adobe-flash

I just downloaded the latest version of adobe flash player from the site https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/!
but,now when I double click on the installed file named "flashplayer21_ga_install.exe" nothing happens. Simple nothing happens.

P.S. I have uninstalled the previous version of flash properly and cleared the other leftover files.

right now, I have no antivirus installed... and Firewall turned off. 
I have checked , in 'safe mode' also, the same thing's happening.
I'm using win-XP.

Comment: Does the version of Flash you are trying to install specifically support `Windows XP`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows XP 64 bit?

[According to Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/tech-specs.html), only 32 bit Adobe Flash is supported, and you need the latest version of the browser you are using,

Also make sure you have at least Service Pack 3. SP 2 or earlier are not supported.

You can use the link provided to make sure you are meeting other system requirements as well,

Comment: can you share the link here ?

Comment: I'm using 32 bit

Comment: I posted it in my answer. Click on the blue text

Comment: okay ! Let me check !

Comment: I'm using 32-bit. but win XP SP2 . Is this new version of adobe not supported in SP2 ?

Comment: That is your problem. You need at least service pack 3

Comment: but till now adobe used to work.  :(

Comment: Adobe may have dropped support for it. Many services no longer support Windows XP in general, let alone service pack 2. Adobe is likely following suit, as it says on their website

Comment: @saudade - Only **Windows XP Service Pack 3** is supported.  Until you install SP3 the version of Flash you are attempting to install cannot be installed.

Comment: okay. I understand. Now, My Dvd drive is not working.i have an ISO file of 'Windows XP PROFESSIONAL SP3' . now How can i install that ?

Comment: You should consider posting this as a seperate problem. You can try installing from USB or try using Windows Update, unless that isn't available anymore for Service Pack 2.

Comment: the win XP I'm using now, I didn't purchase it.